# Symmetry operators of a Bloch Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, topology, second-quantization, topological-insulators

Consider a lattice with a 3 atom basis, e.g. the Lieb lattice, and some completely arbitrary on-site energies and hopping energies and phases between the different atoms. In momentum space we can describe the Hamiltonian by

$$ H = \sum_\mathbf{k} \hat{\Psi}_\mathbf{k}^\dagger \mathcal{H}_\mathbf{k}  \hat{\Psi}_\mathbf{k}$$

where $\hat{\Psi}_\mathbf{k} = \left( a_\mathbf{k}, b_\mathbf{k}, c_\mathbf{k} \right)$ is a vector of annihilation operators for excitations on the A, B and C sublattice (see image below). How do I determine what symmetries the Hamiltonian has? How do I construct the time-reversal $(T)$, particle-hole symmetry $(C)$, and chiral symmetry operators $(S)$ for the Bloch Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}_\mathbf{k}$ and calculate the square value so that I can classify the Hamiltonian in the "periodic table of topological insulators" (see image below).

I don't understand. Surely these things are well defined. But I can't find *anywhere* that gives a straight forward description of how to do this in general (for three bands or any general N-band model).

[image]

[image]